# Why does my Owl carousel javascript works partially?

Tags: javascript

Owl Carousel is Javascript is partially working

i am currently working with owl carousel v2.3.2 and the problem i am facing is that the autoPlay loop doesn't work after the final image in the slider it drags all the images back to start instead of following the loop. i tried to make it work and found a major problem that the half of my js is not working.

```
var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
  owl.owlCarousel({
    margin: 0,
    loop: ($(".owl-carousel .item").length>1)? true :false,
    nav: true,
    pagination: true,
    autoPlay: false,
    responsive: {
      0: {
        items: 1,
        loop: true
      },
      600: {
        items: 1,
        loop: true
      },
      1000: {
        items: 1,
        loop: true

      }
    }
  })
```

the Javascript working from responsive part and all the above code is ignored

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please check this to see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

you sould try to set autoPlay: true .

Comment: nothing is working only responsive is working from the code

Comment: please provide your full source code including HTML ,may you miss something !

Comment: how do i do that

Comment: @Error70 [Avoid brevity, prefer explanations](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Or instead, if the question is unclear, post a comment to the OP for asking some clarifications before answering.